# How to get Bokeh hovertool working for candlesticks chart?

Tags: python, graph, hover, bokeh, alpha-vantage

The goal was to have my mouse hover over the candlesticks and have the data appear while I do so. I was able to get the Bokeh hover tool working but, I am not able to pull and display the data. I was able to get the (x,y) data to appear but, not the rest. This is what I have so far:

```
#Importing Libraries
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
from math import pi

#Request ticker symbol
API_KEY = 'YOUR API KEY'
symbol = input('Enter ticker symbol: ')
r = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=' + symbol + '&apikey=' + API_KEY)
print(r.status_code)
result = r.json()
dataForAllDays = result['Time Series (Daily)']

#convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataForAllDays, orient='index') 
df = df.reset_index()

#rename columns
df = df.rename(index=str, columns={"index": "date", "1. open": "open", "2. high": "high", "3. low": "low", "4. close": "close","5. volume":"volume"})

#Changing to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#Sort according to date
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])

#Changing the datatype 
df.open = df.open.astype(float)
df.close = df.close.astype(float)
df.high = df.high.astype(float)
df.low = df.low.astype(float)
df.volume = df.volume.astype(int)

#check the data
df.head()

#Hovertool Tooltips
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=df['date'], open=df.open, close=df.close))
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),    
    ("date", "@date"),
    ("open", "df.open"),
    ("open", "@open"),
    ("close", "df.close"),
    ("close", "@close"),
    ("percent","@changepercent"),
]

#Check the datatype
df.info()
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
title = symbol + ' Chart'
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, tooltips=TOOLTIPS, plot_width=1000, title = title)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#a30e15", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#53680c", line_color="black")

#Store as a HTML file
output_file("stock_information.html", title="candlestick.py")

# Display in browser
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only values that are meaningful in the tooltip specification, are:

- pre-defined "special variables" denoted by starting with `$`
- references to columns in the ColumnDataSource, denoted by starting with `@`

So things like `"df.open"` are meaningless in this context. The actual code to make the hovertool executes in the browser, in javascript, where Python and Pandas and your DataFrame `df` do not exist. If you want data to show up in a `HoverTool` then you will have to put a column in your CDS with that data, and reference it in the hover tool specification using the `@column_name` syntax.

You may refer to the documentation for more information:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example of functioning one minute candlestick with hover tooltips and bbands thrown in.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('d', '@timestamp{%H:%M}'),
        ('o', '@open{0}'),
        ('h', '@high{0}'),
        ('l', '@low{0}'),
        ('c', '@close{0}'),
        ('v', '@volume{0}'),
    ],

    formatters={
        '@timestamp': 'datetime'
    },
    mode='mouse'
)
inc_b = source.data['close'] > source.data['open']
inc = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(inc_b)])
dec_b = source.data['open'] > source.data['close']
dec = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(dec_b)])
w = 60000

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", sizing_mode="stretch_width", height=400)
p.segment(source=source, x0='timestamp', x1='timestamp', y0='high', y1='low', color="black")
p.vbar(source=source, view=inc, x='timestamp', width=w, top='open', bottom='close', fill_color="green", line_color="green")
p.vbar(source=source, view=dec, x='timestamp', width=w, top='open', bottom='close', fill_color="red", line_color="red")
p.line(source=source, x='timestamp', y='bband_up', line_width=1, alpha=0.8, legend_label='bband_up', color='green')
p.line(source=source, x='timestamp', y='bband_mid', line_width=1, alpha=0.8, legend_label='bband_mid', color='blue')
p.line(source=source, x='timestamp', y='bband_low', line_width=1, alpha=0.8, legend_label='bband_low', color='red')
p.add_tools(hover)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
show(p)
```

[image]